# Application Insights Takes time to send event

Tags: uwp, azure-application-insights

I have developed a UWP application where I have Used the Application Insights to track the page view and custom events of the application.I have also added custom event during application close event, but the application close event is not tracked where as all other custom event and page views are getting tracked.On analysis we found that AI takes some time to send event.Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: Application Insights is an extensible Application Performance Management (APM) service for web developers on multiple platforms. From June 15, 2016, we will stop showing data for iOS, Android, Windows Store, and Windows Phone apps in Application Insights. Instead, you will be able to access this data through HockeyApp. Please refer [Transitioning Mobile Apps from Application Insights to HockeyApp](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transitioning-mobile-apps-from-application-insights-to-hockeyapp/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#flushing-data) commend in the Application Insights SDK makes an effort to flush telemetry left in buffers, but do not guarantee delivery.

One approach to make sure that the last event is being sent is to add a simple `thread.sleep` call before ending the process. However, if you want to make sure that all the events are sent in a synchronous matter, you can implement your own telemetry channel that sends the events before returning.

You can see [the full example here](http://apmtips.com/blog/2016/11/10/sync-channel/), but a simple sync telemetry channel will look like this:

```
class SyncTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
{
    private Uri endpoint = new Uri("https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track");

    public bool? DeveloperMode { get; set; }

    public string EndpointAddress { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Flush() { }

    public void Send(ITelemetry item)
    {
        byte[] json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new List<ITelemetry>() { item }, true);
        Transmission transimission = new Transmission(endpoint, json, "application/x-json-stream", JsonSerializer.CompressionType);
        var t = transimission.SendAsync();
        t.Wait();
    }
}
```